# Modify default endpoint configuration

Tags: apache-camel

Example:

```
to("xslt:mapping.xsl?saxon=true&transformerCacheSize=5")
```

When I use Saxon, I will set this property all over the  place. Having a String constant for them or creating my own `xslt` endpoint does not seem to be the proper way.

Is there something I can set those properties for all `xslt` endpoints?

Comment: Do you use Camel with Spring Boot?

Comment: I'm using it with Spring, Spring Boot for local standalone, but for the production I'm deploying it on EE-server (WebSphere), so I can rely on Spring but not on Spring Boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it by subscribing to the CamelContext's `startupListener` and setting the `XsltEndpoints`' parameters (be careful, because the following example does set every `XsltEndpoint` endpoint's `saxon` and `transformerCacheSize` properties). Example (ctx is an instance of CamelContext):

```
ctx.addStartupListener((ctx, alreadyStarted) -> {
    ctx.getEndpoints().forEach(e -> {
            if(e instanceof XsltEndpoint) {
                ((XsltEndpoint) e).setTransformerCacheSize(5);
                ((XsltEndpoint) e).setSaxon(true);
            }
        });
});
```

In case of Spring Boot `saxon=true` can be configured using the `application.properties` file ([XsltComponentConfiguration](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/platforms/spring-boot/components-starter/camel-core-starter/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/xslt/springboot/XsltComponentConfiguration.java)). AFAIK the `transformerCacheSize` cannot be configured from the properties file, because it is a parameter of the `XsltEndpoint`.

```
# application.properties
camel.component.xslt.saxon = true
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for! As you said it's a bit magic for someone who is new in the project, that the application behaves different from the specification's defaults, but it's a trade off.

Answer (score 0):

If the configuration is always the same, you can declare a direct endpoint to handle all requests.

```
from("direct:my-xslt")
.to("xslt:mapping.xsl?saxon=true&transformerCacheSize=5")
```

And then from your other routes:

```
.to("direct:my-xslt")
```

Direct endpoints run in the same thread, so after all its just a way of isolating parts of the route that do a specific job.

As a bonus if you need to do any kind of transformation/log before/after your xslt that apply to all routes, you can simply do it in your direct route.

Comment: Interesting, but a bit invasive and I have different xslt-mapping files, I would need to provide them in a header, but that gets nasty